# Showing midi pitch numbers from Mid file with music21

Tags: python, midi, music21

I am using music21 to extract the midi pitch numbers (in order) for a bunch of midi files.

I have been reading through the documentation and I can load one file like this:

```
from music21 import *
sBach = corpus.parse('bach/bwv7.7')
```

Now how do I show a sequence of midi numbers? I am sure this is possible but I can't find the function in the documentation.

And is there a way to do it for multiple files at the same time?

Comment: The "Plotting pitches and durations continuously in music21" example at http://web.mit.edu/music21/ shows how to read note numbers. See also http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleStream.html#music21.stream.Stream.notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from music21 import *
sBach = corpus.parse('bach/bwv7.7')
for p in sBach.parts:
    print("Part: ", p.id)
    for n in p.flat.notes:
        print(n.pitch.midi)
```

Note that `.notes` includes `Chord` objects, which don't have a `.pitch` property.  So for complex scores you may need to separate out the chords from notes or iterate over `p.pitches`. I think you'll want to go through the music21 [User's Guide](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_02_notes.html) a bit more before continuing.